# convert to POSIXct with format not working with %B

Tags: r, posixct

Both the following two lines of code return NA.

```
as.POSIXct("1-March-2021 11:45", format="%d-%B-%Y %H:%M")
as.POSIXct("1-Mar-2021 11:45", format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M")
```

But if I change `March` to `3`, it works fine.

```
as.POSIXct("1-3-2021 11:45", format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
```

I am stuck here. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: It could be that locale settings have a different language other than english.  If it is french, it could be `mars` instead of March.  For me it is working `as.POSIXct("1-March-2021 11:45", format="%d-%B-%Y %H:%M")#
[1] "2021-03-01 11:45:00 IST"`

Comment: Indeed. It is the language setting problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your OS?  This works here (on Ubuntu)

```r
> as.POSIXct("1-March-2021 11:45", format="%d-%B-%Y %H:%M")
[1] "2021-03-01 11:45:00 CST"
> as.POSIXct("1-Mar-2021 11:45", format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M")
[1] "2021-03-01 11:45:00 CST"
>
```

Localization may matter too.  I am in a US-English one:

```r
> Sys.getenv("LANG")
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
>
```